# Tabular Form for Insertion ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, tabular

I want to create a tabular form in Asp.net for multiple insertions at a time.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more by example what you really means ? Also what is the tabular form, do you have some examples, some links, do you have see the asp.net tabs around the internet and no one work for you ?

Comment: I want to create a tabular form like oracle developer provides. i want a grid that should allow me multiple enteries at a time. however one by one entry is also acceptable like Listview, the problem is i dont want to run the default insert, cause i want to insert values in some columns without user input. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to go on there with your question, but perhaps you are looking for the ListView or GridView controls? I would suggest you look at those and see if that is what you want, or update your question with further details.

Comment: i am new to asp and want to create tabular form like oracle developer(form 6i or 10g). list view can be used. but i want to insert through a procedure one form. how to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with oracle developer(form 6i or 10g) and I'm still not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to have a few rows of text boxes where you can insert more than one row into the DB? If so you'll have to create a UserControl.

Look at this:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)